# vkDestroyDevice returns vkDevice has not been Destroyed and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vulkan

Running MacOS Catalina and VSCode.

This is how I initialize my device

```
void Renderer::InitDevice() {
    {
        uint32_t gpu_count = 0;
        vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(Instance, &gpu_count, nullptr);
        std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> gpu_list(gpu_count);
        vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(Instance, &gpu_count, gpu_list.data()); //populates gpu_list with all gpu handles
        GPU = gpu_list[0]; //grab first gpu. debug and figure out a ranking system
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(GPU, &GPU_device_properties);
    }

    {
        uint32_t family_count = 0;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(GPU, &family_count, nullptr);
        std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> family_properties(family_count);
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(GPU, &family_count, family_properties.data());


        bool found_graphics_bit = false;
        for ( u_int32_t i = 0; i<family_count; i++){
            if(family_properties[i].queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT){
                found_graphics_bit = true;
                graphics_family_index = i;
            }
        }
        if (!found_graphics_bit){
            assert(1 && "Vulkan Error: Queue family supporting graphics card not found");
            std::exit(-1);
        }

    }
    {
        uint32_t layer_count = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layer_count, nullptr);
        std::vector<VkLayerProperties> layer_properties(layer_count);
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layer_count, layer_properties.data()); //something about system layers
        std::cout << "Instance Layers: \n";
        for (auto &layer_property: layer_properties){
            std::cout << "\t" << layer_property.layerName << "\n";
            std::cout << "\t\t" << layer_property.description << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

    }
        {
        uint32_t layer_count = 0;
        vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(GPU, &layer_count, nullptr);
        std::vector<VkLayerProperties> layer_properties(layer_count);
        vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(GPU, &layer_count, layer_properties.data()); //something about system layers
        std::cout << "Device Layers: \n";
        for (auto &layer_property: layer_properties){
            std::cout << "\t" << layer_property.layerName << "\n";
            std::cout << "\t\t" << layer_property.description << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

    }


    float queue_priorities[] { 1.0f };
    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo device_queue_info = {};
    //need to understand queue properties
    device_queue_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    device_queue_info.queueFamilyIndex = graphics_family_index;
    device_queue_info.queueCount = 1;
    device_queue_info.pQueuePriorities = queue_priorities;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo device_info{};
    device_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    device_info.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
    device_info.pQueueCreateInfos = &device_queue_info;
    device_info.enabledLayerCount = device_layers.size();
    device_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = device_layers.data();
    device_info.enabledExtensionCount = device_extensions.size();
    device_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = device_extensions.data();

   auto err = vkCreateDevice(GPU, &device_info, nullptr, &Device);
   if (err != VK_SUCCESS){
        assert(1 && "Vulkan Error: Device Creation Failed");
        std::exit(-1);
   }
}
```

Vulkan device creation return VK_SUCCESS when this error occurs.
And this is how I destroy it

```
void Renderer::DeinitDevice() {
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(Device);
    vkDestroyDevice(Device, nullptr); //uncommenting this causes program to crash.
    Device = nullptr;
}
```

on `vkDeviceWaitIdle(Device);` or if that is removed it happens on `vkDestroyDevice(Device, nullptr);`

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

and

```
@"2020-05-17 15:06:54.832625-0400 main[4816:29494] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35\r\n"
@"UNASSIGNED-ObjectTracker-ObjectLeak(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 699204130 - Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-ObjectTracker-ObjectLeak ] Object 0: handle = 0x10104e018, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x29ad0222 | OBJ ERROR : VK_DEBUG_REPORT_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE_EXT object VkDevice 0x10104e018[] has not been destroyed.\r\n"
@"    Objects: 1\r\n"
@"        [0] 0x10104e018, type: 3, name: NULL\r\n"
```

I was following the vulkan-tutorial and I couldn't really understand that but I found a few videos that explained the things the tutorial really doesn't go over. So far I've put this together but I'm not sure what's causing the error. I've seen other similar errors but can't seem to find out how they fixed it.

Comment: I assume you're using MoltenVK for the Vulkan support (since macOS doesn't have native Vulkan support). If so, you should edit the tags to include the [tag:moltenvk] tag.

Comment: I will look into MoltenVK, My actual issue for this was I was destroying the instance before destroying the device. I assume the destroying the instance destroys the device as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code I didn't post that actually contained the issue was this

```
Renderer::~Renderer(){
    DestroyInstance();
    DeinitDevice();
}
```

I transposed these two from the tutorial I was following on accident. and should be this

```
Renderer::~Renderer(){
    DeinitDevice();
    DestroyInstance();
}
```